# How to print collection mysql query in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, query

There is `getSelect()->__toString();` is available in Magento 1 for print query of collection. like below example

```
$products = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)
 ->addAttributeToFilter(‘status’, array(‘eq’ => 1));
echo $products->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Is there any method available in Magento 2?
I have found this `->printLogQuery(true);` but doesn't work for me.

Update:
below is the code. I am trying to get the best seller products. It works perfect but I want to print a query for debugging.

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()
                  ->joinLeft(
                'sales_order_item',
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
                array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('qty_ordered '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
```

Comment: Please post the full code you're testing `printLogQuery` with

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelatDigitalPianism for quick comment. I have revise question with code.

Comment: you can try with $this->_collection->getSelect();

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The answers above are correct, but some collections only assemble the select in the `_beforeLoad()` method, as opposed to initialising it in the constructor. This means you'll get an empty string if you try to output the SQL query before loading the collection.

An example of this is `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection`. So if you're getting unexpected results then load the collection (this will build the final select query) and then output the query.

```
$collection->load();

// the following statements are equivalent
$collection->getSelect()->assemble();
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
echo $collection->getSelect(); // will call magic method __toString() behind the scenes which in turn calls assemble()
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use **__toString()** function to print query in Magento 2

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use same as magento 1 to print query in magento 2.

```
$collection = $this->_collection->getSelect()
                      ->joinLeft(
                    'sales_order_item',
                    'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
                    array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                    ->group('e.entity_id') 
                    ->order('qty_ordered '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());

$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: Perfect. I haven't same for M2. its work perfect!

Answer (score 6):

Or, simply use

```
echo $collection->getSelect()
```

Answer (score 2):

var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());

Answer (score 1):

i hope you want to print query to identify the issue of getsize count wrong. whenever you use group by query then call getSize function means it will give first record data so it will give wrong count. for this before embed group by query. you should call getSize function. so it will set before execute group by query.

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply you can use

```
echo $collection->getSelectSql(true)
```