# where prepared query to base can see

Tags: magento2.3, database

For example my repository get items by getList($searchCriteria) where I can see prepared query to base like this SELECT * FROM table. I am use xdebug so I need a line of breakpoint or name of function. Magento2.3

Comment: this might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107361/magento-2-log-database-queries

Comment: You are using xdebug but can't use "Step into"?

Comment: thanks its helpful but I need something like this $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); like in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166536/how-to-print-collection-mysql-query-in-magento-2

Comment: I can use step into but its hundreds off steps, I need shortest path