# Get Latest Entry For Duplicate Rows In Collection

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, query, duplicate

I currently have a logs table which has the following rows which use the same `order_id`:

| log_id | order_id | user | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 1001318004 | test1 | Declined |
| 2409 | 1001318004 | test1 | Declined |

Inside my `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/OrderTable/Collection.php` class file I have the following method to set the collection results:

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->from(['main_table' => $this->getMainTable()]);

        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['logs' => $this->getTable('logs')],
                'main_table.increment_id = logs.order_id',
                ['*','customer_name'=>'CONCAT_WS(" ",main_table.customer_firstname,main_table.customer_lastname)']
            );

        return $this->filterOrders();
    }
```

where `main_table` references the `sales_order` table.

but when I view the results in the admin I get the following error:

`Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "1557472" already exists.`

The `1557472` refers to the entity ID matching the order for the `1001318004` increment ID.

What I'm looking for, is a way to only get the latest row if there are duplicates in the results.

Cheers guys

Comment: If this one is your log table 'innox_prescriber_logs' then try like this " main_table.increment_id = innox_prescriber_logs.order_id ". and let me know it is working or not

Comment: Hi Viru, sorry about that, just realised that was the incorrect code I previously had in there, but I have updated it now so could you please take another look if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: can you print your query which is created collection and check what is your query. use this to print query https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166536/how-to-print-collection-mysql-query-in-magento-2

Comment: Okey dokey, here is the output from the select query:


```"SELECT `main_table`.*, `logs`.*, CONCAT_WS(" ",main_table.customer_firstname,main_table.customer_lastname) AS `customer_name` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `logs` ON main_table.increment_id = logs.order_id"```

but what I need, is for it to return only the latest rows for duplicate entries.

Comment: you can use for return only $this or $this->getSelect() and check.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean sorry? :)

Comment: as of now you have to return like "return $this->filterOrders();"  So now you try with "return $this;" OR "return $this->getSelect()"

Comment: let me know it is working or not

Comment: Ah I see what you mean sorry. So the reason for calling $this->filterOrders, is it will call to this method to see whether or not to sort the results based on a request parameter, e.g.



protected function filterOrders()
    {
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() === 'doctor_index_index') {
            $this->addOrder('urgent', 'DESC');
        }

        return $this;
    }

Comment: yup now results showing fine?

Comment: nope, lol, that's how I end up with the `Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "1557472" already exists.
` error. It's finding duplicate rows with the same order_id value, I need to say, "get me the latest entry row for any duplicate rows" if you get me?

Comment: Viru, I have managed to solve this one now and posted the answer, but thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: SNAFU! yup Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a long time of troubleshooting this, I have finally resolved it. So here is the solution for anyone else who encounters a similar problem.

The initial method:

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->from(['main_table' => $this->getMainTable()]);

        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['logs' => $this->getTable('logs')],
                'main_table.increment_id = logs.order_id',
                ['*','customer_name'=>'CONCAT_WS(" ",main_table.customer_firstname,main_table.customer_lastname)']
            );

        return $this->filterOrders();
    }
```

the new method:

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->from(['main_table' => $this->getMainTable()]);

        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        // first we create a query which gets the max value for the row id, and then groups the results on order_id 
        $groupedResults = $connection->select();
        $groupedResults
            ->from(['logs_grouped' => 'logs'])
            ->reset($groupedResults::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(
                [
                    'max_id' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("max(`logs_grouped`.`log_id`)"),
                ]
            )
            ->group('order_id');

        // we create another query which will match the row id values, with the max id values from our grouped set, giving us the latest entries from the duplicates
        $logs = $connection->select();
        $logs
            ->from(['logs' => 'logs'])
            ->reset($logs::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(
                '*'
            )->joinInner(
                ['logs_grouped' => $groupedResults],
                'logs.log_id = logs_grouped.max_id'
            );

        // finally, we left join our new $logs table to the main table (in this case the sales_order table)
        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['logs' => $logs],
                'main_table.increment_id = logs.order_id',
                ['*','customer_name'=>'CONCAT_WS(" ",main_table.customer_firstname,main_table.customer_lastname)']
            );

        return $this;
    }
```

so instead of:

| log_id | order_id | user | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 1001318004 | test1 | Declined |
| 2409 | 1001318004 | test1 | Declined |

we now get:

| log_id | order_id | user | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 1001318004 | test1 | Declined |

giving us the row with the latest id :)